# How to construct homogeneous subsets table for nonparametric tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, post-hoc, zero-inflation, representative

Does post-hoc for friedman tests or nonparametric testshave like a homogeneous subset table from SPSS? Mean doesn't represent it well so I tried using median but my data was zero-inflated so the most of the medians even in supposed homogeneous groups have lots of zeroes

Example:
[image: homogeneous subsets]

Comment: What is a _homogeneous subset table_?  Is it obtained from data dredging?  Have you verified that your sample size is adequate for the simplest possible analysis?

Comment: @FrankHarrell it's like another way of representing the post-hoc pairwise comparisons. in the example above, it's the column "1" or "2" which contain the mean of the groups which are significantly different to the mean in other columns. so that "Control group" (5.30) is significantly different than Mnemonic A (11.80) and Mnemonic B (15.60). Now the problem is the mean is not representative when the test is nonparametric

Comment: Yes that's what I'd usually call data dredging, a very dangerous practice without careful multiplicity corrections.  Long-term one of the better ways to think about this is getting simultaneous confidence intervals for all differences of interest.  These would come from a unified model for count data, or perhaps better, from a semiparametric model such as the proportional odds model which can handle extreme clumping at zero.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's just my first time hearing "data dredging" so I did a quick informal search and I guess in a way "data dredging" concept exists in post-hoc analysis as well (???) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_analysis)

Comment: It's concentrated there.